# LA Noire: Do you get any bonus for 100% Completion?

Tags: la-noire

Simple question, really.

Do you get any bonus for 100% Completion in LA Noire? GTAIV unlocked certain things, as I remember, once you'd gotten 100% (although nothing you couldn't use cheat codes to get). Is there anything different in the game once you've unlocked 100% completion in LA Noire?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are playing the game on Xbox 360 or Playstation 3, you unlock the achievement/trophy called "The City of Angels".

Other than this, **no**, you **do not** unlock any bonuses for completing the game, unlike in GTAIV.